# Call to a Soap WS, results on "Couldn't get a SAX parser while constructing a envelope" error

Tags: web-services, sax, spring-ws, saxparser, saaj

During a call to a Soap WebService we hit into this error. What could be the reason behind ?

I'm using JDK 7 update U67 (64 Bits), Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Spring WS 2.1.0.RELEASE (spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar),

Here is the stacktrace log:

```
----- ERROR [7-thread-1] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.webservice.WebServiceCallTemplateImpl:45 An error occured when connecting to service.
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Couldn't get a SAX parser while constructing a envelope; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Couldn't get a SAX parser while constructing a envelope
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:260)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:342)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:117)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:186)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:589)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:384)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:374)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.commons.webservice.WebServiceCallTemplateImpl.sendAndReceive(WebServiceCallTemplateImpl.java:38)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.commons.webservice.WebServiceCallTemplateImpl.sendAndReceiveNoError(WebServiceCallTemplateImpl.java:73)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.commons.webservice.ServerCallTemplate.sendAndReceiveNoError(ServerCallTemplate.java:61)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxClient.readDocument(QaDocumentReaderClient.java:39)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxService.readDocument(QaDocumentReadService.java:44)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$50e93444.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$98b68ed1.readDocument(<generated>)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRunnable.run(QaDocumentReadRunnable.java:38)
at WICKET_com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.QaDocumentReadRunnable$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ab78176e.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:333)
at WICKET_com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRunnable$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$46e7e20f.run(<generated>)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Couldn't get a SAX parser while constructing a envelope
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils.getSaajVersion(SaajUtils.java:155)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getSaajVersion(SaajSoapMessage.java:257)
... 34 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException
java.lang.InterruptedException
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ParserPool.get(Unknown Source)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
... 40 more
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that the thread on which the SOAP call is running has been interrupted, and the particular method shown in the stack trace (`com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ParserPool#get()`) just happens to execute the first call to an interruptible method after that interrupt happened. Since the thread belongs to a thread pool, this may be caused by a call to the `shutdownNow()` method of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: If you are using the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler that Spring provides, make sure you do
```.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true)``` before the ```shutdown()``` call

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, shutdownNow() was the root reason behind this issue. As a solution, shutdownNow() was replaced by shutdown() for the following reason :

- shutdownNow() tells the executor service (ScheduledExecutorService) that it can't accept new tasks and try to cancel the already submitted tasks by interrupting the relevant threads where the thrown java.lang.InterruptedException, whereas method shutdown() will just tell the executor service that it can't accept new tasks, **but the already submitted tasks continue to run till the end.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, and it was caused by me calling close on the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` returned from the run method in

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args).close();
    }
}
```

Removing the `.close()` made the interrupt go away.